# StringIndexOutOfBoundsException when trying to evaluate file input?

Tags: java

I get a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` for the line reading `(line.charAt(0) == 'I')`, where it says `String index is out of range at 0`.

I'm not sure what to do here.

```
QueueLinkedList<Customer> eventqueue = new QueueLinkedList<Customer>();
QueueLinkedList<Customer> customerqueue = new QueueLinkedList<Customer>();
int numberserved = 0, totalidletime = 0, longestbreak = 0, idletime = 0, linelength = 0, longestline = 0;

try {
    File file = new File("customersfile.txt");
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));

    String line;
    while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        //empty lines
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != "") {
            //first line of file
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != "300") {
                Customer newcust = new Customer();
                if (line.charAt(0) == 'I') {
                    newcust.id = line.charAt(11);
                }
                else {
                    newcust.arrtime = line.substring(14);
                    newcust.setarrtimesecs(newcust.arrtime);
                    newcust.setleavingtime(newcust.arrtime);    
                }
                eventqueue.enqueue(newcust);
            }
        } 
    }
}catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Why you use reader.readLine()) != null why not just hasNextLine(), I think your way will keep real empty lines

Answer (score 0):

This line is blank, there is no character at index 0 then this string is empty. You are executing this line:

```
line.charAt(0) == 'I'
```

Try like this way,

```
if (line.trim().length() > 0 && line.charAt(0) == 'I') {
```

Answer (score 0):

In your second while loop you need to `trim` before comparing to `""`.

```
while ((line = reader.readLine().trim()) != "") {
```

And also compare with equals, because `!=` operator compares if references point to the same object.